# Copy records from multiple workbooks in a folder to a summary workbook

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Sceenshot]

There are multiple workbooks like in this format in a folder. I need the records that are other than `'@gmail.com'` in the summary workbook.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .In short, you'll need to show your code attempts to solve this and where it's not working to get the most help on this site. If you also post a screenshot of a sample of your sheet, that would help us help you more as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you. You might need to add the Scripting Runtime reference in order to use the FileSystemObject.

```
Sub GetMail()

Dim MySht As Worksheet
Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
Dim SrcSht As Worksheet
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim Fl As File

Set MySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
MySht.Range("A1").Value = "Procedure"
MySht.Range("B1").Value = "Email"

'Loop through all of the files in the folder
For Each Fl In FSO.GetFolder("").Files
    'Open the file
    Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fl.Path)
    Set SrcSht = SrcWbk.Sheets(1)
    'Loop down all of the rows
    For x = 2 To SrcSht.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        'Check if it's a @Gmail.com address
        If InStr(1, UCase(SrcSht.Cells(x, 2).Value), "@GMAIL.COM") = 0 Then
            If MySht.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
                MySht.Range("A2").Value = SrcSht.Cells(x, 1).Value
                MySht.Range("A2").Offset(0, 1).Value = SrcSht.Cells(x, 2).Value
            Else
                MySht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = SrcSht.Cells(x, 1).Value
                MySht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 1).Value = SrcSht.Cells(x, 2).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set SrcSht = Nothing
    SrcWbk.Close False
    Set SrcWbk = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Jason. thank you very much for the code. However I tried running this code I am not getting the desired output.
exp: I have 3 files in a folder having the data as above mentioned. I ran the macro that you created, the macro only collects one of the mismatch data from one sheet and does not list the entire list of mismatch id's from the files in the folder. I am guessing there is overwrite issue in the first row of the output sheet. If you could suggest me what can be done it would be great.

Comment: Hi Atul, sorry about that, I've spotted the error with the original code and made an edit. Try again and let me know the results.

Comment: Hey Jason, I tried this updated code and it works fine except the issue here is that in the output sheet all the expected records are overwriting in one row it self i.e row 2. It is not taking the next blank row to write the result. Can you assist me once again. Thank you for taking interest in this issue

Comment: Hi Atul, I've made another edit. This time I promise it will work! Sorry I couldn't get it right first time.

Comment: Yessss!!!!!... It finally worked. you are the best :) Appreciate your support jason.

Comment: Brilliant, if you don't mind could you mark my answer as useful?